# Proof matrix eigenvalues inside the unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that matrix $A$ is set as:
$A=(I-P)\left(I+(I-QP)^{-1}QP\right)$. 
Could this equation be simplified written as: $A=(I-P)(I-QP)^{-1}$ and how could I proof the eigenvalues of $A$ are inside the unit circle?

Conditions for P and Q are:
$P=diag(p_{1},\cdots,p_{n})$ and $p_{i}\in[0,1)$.
$q_{i,j}$ in $Q$ are in interval $[0,1]$ and all the diagonal elements $q_{i,i}=0$

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question, $$(I-QP)^{-1}QP=(I-QP)^{-1}(QP-I)+(I-QP)^{-1}=-I+(I-QP)^{-1}$$ $$\therefore\ I+(I-QP)^{-1}QP=(I-QP)^{-1}$$

For the second part, the eigenvalues need not be bounded in the unit circle. Take $P=\alpha I$, $0<\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$, then $$A=(1-\alpha)(I-\alpha Q)^{-1}$$ It is enough to choose $Q$ symmetric such that $Q$ has an eigenvalue greater than one. For example, take $$Q=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\textrm{Eigenvalues of $Q$ are }2,-1,-1$$ $$\textrm{Eigenvalues of $I-\alpha Q$ are }1-2\alpha,1+\alpha$$ $$\textrm{Eigenvalues of $A$ are }\frac{1-\alpha}{1-2\alpha},\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}$$ The first eigenvalue is greater than one.